# Were electrons initially left-handed, as neutrinos still are today?

Tags: electrons, chirality

These days, neutrinos are left-handed, just as they were a long time ago. These days electrons are right- as well as left-handed. Were they only left-handed a long time ago, before having interacted with any force field?

I can imagine that neutrinos still are left-handed today as they barely reacted with matter. Electrons have reacted though, and maybe they have developed a right-handed portion well as a left-handed portion. They don't move at lightspeed anymore (so at lightspeed after just after creation).

Before the Higgs field became effective, all particles moved at the speed of light. Wouldn't the theory be more symmetric if besides left-handed neutrinos, also one-chirality electrons were created? Or is a theory with two chiralities from the start more symmetric (for both the electron and the neutrino)?

Comment: What makes you think this is even a possibility?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Symmetry

Comment: Right handed neutrinos are perfectly fine in the model, they just interact solely via gravitational interaction. Being right handed only excludes them from the weak interaction, same as the right handed electron. The right handed electron can at least still interact via electromagnetism.

Comment: @Triatticus So you say that initially there were two types of electrons?

Comment: Seriously, why these amount of downvotes?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder what I'm saying is the statement that there isn't a right handed neutrino isn't really true, it's just such a particle is hard to detect. One possibility being it might enter into oscillations with the left handed neutrinos.

Comment: @Triatticus But the inability to detect them surely introduces an asymmetry?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder no, there is a difference between not being able to be detected and not being present at all. No detection isn't necessarily an indication of not being present. That is caused by the CP violation in the weak sector.

Comment: @Triatticus But actually we don't know about right handed neutrino yet. It may not exist at all - neutrino may get Majorana masses through some new physics loop corrections like it does in some $R_p$ violating MSSM models. It may also get huge mass through seesaw mechanism, then the neutrino we detect can only have tiny mixing with right handed one.

Comment: @Triatticus Why is CP symmetry violated?

Comment: @Triatticus Don't right-handed neutrinos cause gravitational attraction?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder That only left-handed components of the fermions participate in the weak interaction is more or less equivalent to the statement that C and P are violated (note that I used them separately). The combined CP may actually be preserved, it is violated in certain ways W bosons change the generation of the particles. Now why C and P are violated, why only left handed particles interact weakly? We don't know yet and need more data about more fundamental physics to check any hypotheses about that.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Everything interacts gravitationaly. But if you would to pinpoint the particle responsible for the gravitational force, forget about all other known stuff except graviton. We know that it should be a particle with certain characteristics (spin 2 massless, interacting in a certain way) and know that all the stuff we know can't combine to produce gravity

Comment: @OON What I meant is that if right-handed neutrinos exist, what is their contribution to the overall gravitation in the universe? Isn't doubling the number of neutrinos rather significant, or are right-handed neutrinos taken into consideration too in calculating the total gravity produced by neutrinos (they were even thought once to be the dark matter)?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder right handed neutrinos have been proposed before as some version of dark matter or related, depends on the model being proposed.

Answer (score 3):

A massive particle in its rest frame is equal parts left- and right-handed.  There is a correlation between chirality and spin which appears at high momentum; chirality is a frame-dependent observable.

The weak charged current (associated with the $W$ bosons) is a mechanism for interactions between the left-handed parts of matter particles and the right-handed parts of antimatter particles. The products of charged weak decays therefore tend to be polarized, with the polarization stronger if the decay is more energetic.  That's why, for instance, the pseudoscalar pion prefers $\pi^+\to\mu^+\nu_\mu$ over $\pi^+\to e^+\nu_e$, even though the latter would liberate much more energy: the charged lepton has to be polarized the "wrong way" to make the final state spinless.

The polarization of beta-electrons was actually discovered in the 1920s by Cox and collaborators, who were doing some of the earliest experiments on Mott scattering and discovered that they needed to use a thermal electron source rather than a beta emitter for their "control" experiment to give a null result. The significance of the discovery was not understood until the fall of parity in 1957.

Neutrinos and electrons are *both* equal parts left- and right-handed in their rest frames. The difference is that, because the electron is more massive and participates in electromagnetism, it's much easier to interact with an electron so that its rest frame is the same as your rest frame.